# Is agreement required between subject and prepositional phrase?

Tags: grammar

Which is correct (and have you got a source)?

"Animals store vitamin C in their liver."

"Animals store vitamin C in their livers."

Comment: This is not related to prepositional phrases, but to the number of _ownees_ by a number of _owners_. If the livers in question are in the object position, the exact same problem appears: “Alcoholics tend to damage their liver(s)”.

Comment: An animal stores vitamin C in its liver.

Comment: You're dealing with **Generic** noun phrases here. The plural of _Animals_ is not a real plural, but a [plural generic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html); it doesn't individuate -- i.e, you can't depend on one liver per animal -- since it's not referential, but generic.

Comment: @John: even if it was not generic but referential, you still couldn't differentiate. *"The team members are putting on their uniforms and their shoes"* ... each member has one uniform and two shoes, but there is no way to tell that from context; you must use the plural here.

Comment: Nah, if the animal is generic, so is their liver. So any Vitamin C in a generic animal can be stored in the generic liver. No plural necessary; with generics, the plural marker doesn't mean plurality as such.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a source, but see below, all four are valid sentences that mean something different.

> The attendant is loading things in my car.

I have one car, and an attendant is loading things into it.

> The attendant is loading things in my cars.

I have more than one car, and a single attendent is loading things in each of them.

> The attendants are loading things in my car.

I have one car, and multiple attendants are loading things into it.  I'm getting great service here.

> The attendants are loading things in my cars.

I have multiple cars, and multiple attendants are loading things into each of them.  I must be rich or something.  :)

The lines can be blurred with indefinte nouns but the rules still work the same.

Regarding your original example, the second sentence:

> Animals store vitamin C in their livers

could be construed as saying the animals you are talking about have more than one liver, though a native English speaker is likely to understand you mean one animal = one liver (because that's how things are usually) unless the context was different.

Really, to be clear, you want to say:

> Each animal stores vitamin C in its liver

or

> Animals store vitamin C in the liver